# I need to select an element "x" from a website, but the website loads element"x" too slowly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to select a table element from a website, and I am using document.querySelectorAll() to do so. However, the website, I believe, is retrieving that data from another sever and taking time to do so. Therefore, when I try using querySelectorAll() it comes out as undefined.

I've tried adding some event listeners like window.addEventListener("load"), document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded), and window.onload() = funciton().

I think those event listeners don't work because technically the window/DOM content is all officially loaded, but the table I needed is just being inserted later. Is there any way to wait for the table to be loaded so I can access it?

Comment: Do you know how the data is retrieved, e.g. is there an iframe that loads or is it inserted directly by another script? (T.J. Crowder's answer should work just fine for the script method. You might be able to just use an event listener for an iframe though)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`mutation observer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to listen for changes to the childList (and possibly subtree) of a parent (or ancestor) of the element that's there when your code runs (in the worst case, `body`), then when the observer gets called, check for element X.

Live Example:

```js
// Example if you need to use an ancestor

const ob = new MutationObserver(records => {
    const div = document.querySelector(".the-element");
    if (div) {
        ob.disconnect();
        console.log("Got it");
    }
});
ob.observe(
  document.getElementById("ancestor"),
  {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true // Only need this if it's an ancestor
  }
);

// Simulates loading the element later
setTimeout(() => {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = "the-element";
  div.textContent = "I'm the element";
  document.getElementById("parent").appendChild(div);
}, 800);
```

```html
<div id="ancestor">
  <div id="parent">
    Parent
  </div>
</div>
```